# mvc custom login function need to secure controllers

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a function called AuthenticateUsers that returns valid or invalid to my cshtml but i user knows the controller name they would be abke to bypass the login page. How to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to look at this tutorial (https://www.codeproject.com/articles/578374/aplusbeginner-splustutorialplusonpluscustomplusf) and then improve your question. With no code to accompany what your asking, it's impossible to give a good answer.

Comment: yes, this question is way too broad. Answers would need to be too long for this site to provide value. Read some tutorials on this topic or narrow down your question, show some code, etc,., so that others can help with specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

The  [**ActionFilterAttribute Class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.98).aspx) can be applied to either a Controller or an Action.

Your existing `AuthenticateUsers` method could be used to toggle a session dependent field (eg IsAuthenticated) and then the `ActionFilter` could be used to check the value. If it returns false you would redirect back to your *AuthenticateUsers* action

Without any code on your part, I am unable to show you how to implement.